# Variable not updating in jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
var thumbw = $('.video-thumbs li').width();
var feedw = $('.video-thumbs').width();
var thumbx = Math.floor(feedw/thumbw);


$('.scroll-right').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().each(function () {

      var scrollx = $(this).scrollLeft();
      var thumbcount = Math.floor(scrollx/thumbw);
      var nextscroll = thumbcount + thumbx;
      var nextthumb = 'li:nth-child(' + nextscroll + ')';
      var childx = $(this).find(nextthumb).offset().left;
      $(this).animate({ scrollLeft: childx - 40 }, 500, 'linear');
  }); 
});
```

I'm making a side scrolling list of thumbnails. The feed of thumbnails is the parent of the ".scroll-right" button. When you click ".scroll-right" the feed should set the scroll value to the position of the left edge of the first thumbnail in the next set. My problem is that it works for the first one, but afterwards the childx variable doesn't update. Any ideas how I could make this work?

Comment: `$(this).parent()` would only return single element.

Comment: The feed of thumbnails is the parent of the .scroll-right button

Comment: Why the `each` if you know it's a single element in the set?

Comment: What do I use instead when it's just one element?

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
var childx = $(this).find(nextthumb).offset().left;
```

I was using '.offset().left' instead of '.position().left' so the childx variable was taking the thumbnail's position relative to the document rather than its parent element. So I just changed it to:

```
var childx = $(this).find(nextthumb).position().left;
```

and it worked!